# How to sort the WordPress Query by a custom date?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

So I have a custom post type called "Events". In each event, i have a custom field called "start_time_date" which returns a date like "08/01/12". How would i sort these posts to return the posts so that the posts are sorted by the start_time_date in an ascending order (start_time_dates closer to current date gets shown first).

Here's my current code:

```
<? query_posts("cat=$currentID&showposts=100"); ?>
<? if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <? while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); if (time() < strtotime(get('end_time_date'))) :?>

       <? $originalDate = get('start_time_date'); $newDate = date("M j, Y", strtotime($originalDate)); ?>
       <div class="post">Some Post Data</div>

    <? endif; endwhile; ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
<? query_posts("cat=$currentID&showposts=100&orderby=date&order=asc"); ?>
```

I am not sure what exactly `date` is in the database columns but it's something like that. Also, the order might need to but changed but I don't think it matters.

**Edit**

I did some more research and `&orderby=date&order=asc` is correct for the date and ordering.

Sorry about that, did you read through [Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) in the WordPress codex?

They also added `query_posts('&meta_key=popularity&orderby=meta_value');` where `meta_key` is the name of your custom field.

Found here: [Class Reference/WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: Yes. That only sorts by the default WordPress post date. I am trying to sort by a custom date field

Answer (score 1):

Use a meta field that stores a date in a mysql format i.e. `2012-08-02` for that post. Maybe consider using the jquery date picker to render this format for you.

This post when saved should now have a row in the the wp_postmeta table.

```
$results = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'date', 'orderby'=> 'meta_value' ));
```